# How to Group by rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Here is my test table(Still have many more columns). I have just shown some of the columns here.

```
index   DateTime    Biomass Fossil Brown coal/Lignite   Fossil Coal-derived gas 
0   2/3/2018 23:00  4815    17359       192                 
1   2/3/2018 23:15  4811    17364       192 
2   2/3/2018 23:30  4801    17356       192
```

Here i want to SUM the (Biomass, Fossil Brown coal/Lignite, Fossil Coal-derived gas) for each row.

I have tried this.

```
select SUM([Biomass], [Fossil Brown coal/Lignite,Fossil Coal-derived gas])
From test
Where ID = '0'
Group by DateTime
```

But not getting the result as expected.
The expected result will be (4815+17359+192 = 22366)

Can somebody suggest me where it went wrong?

Comment: `ID` ?  What ID?  I see `index`.  Further, DateTime is unique for each row, is it not?  Do you want one number for the whole row?

Comment: Not sure you need to `group` or `sum`?  Can you not just add them together -- `biosmass + fossil + ...`?  If you do need to group them, you probably want to group by the date, not the datetime.  In which case, use `sum`, but still with adding them together `sum(a + b + c)`...

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL.. Please only tag the DBMS you are actually using. Also, do you really have a column called `[Fossil Brown coal/Lignite,Fossil Coal-derived gas]`? You should really avoid special characters (including whitespace) in an object name.

Comment: @sgeddes  Actually DateTime is column name.

Comment: @PraveenRB I meant something like `group by cast([datetime] as date)` -- grouping by the timestamp will probably not group too many records together.  Depends on your desired results.  So for your sample data, if you want 3 results returned, no need for sum or group by, just add them with +.  If you want 1 result by date (not by time), then group them and sum them....

Comment: You only want the sum for the first record (`id = 0`)? You already get this one record with your `WHERE` clause. So why do you group by `datetime`? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Actually i want to query this from the web service, it will send DateTime dynamically to fetch the corresponding row.

Comment: Then it would not be `id` you are filtering by in the `WHERE` clause, but `datetime`. Still this has nothing to do with `GROUP BY`. Or am I misunderstanding this somehow?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes i need to filter it by datetime not ID. You're correct.

Comment: Your syntax suggests that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems want :

```
SELECT [DateTime], SUM(Biomass + [Fossil Brown coal/Lignite] + [Fossil Coal-derived gas])
FROM test t
WHERE ID = '0'
GROUP BY [DateTime];
```

EDIT : Your error suggest `MySQL`, So your Query would be

```
SELECT `DateTime`, SUM(`Biomass` + `Fossil Brown coal/Lignite` + `Fossil Coal-derived gas`)
FROM `test` t
WHERE `ID` = '0'
GROUP BY `DateTime`;
```

Comment: showing select is not valid for this server version.

Comment: @PraveenRB That doesn't sound like a SQL Server error

Comment: @YogeshSharma   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[DateTime], SUM(Biomass + [Fossil Brown coal/Lignite] + [Fossil Coal-derived gas' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You use SUM() when you need to SUM the rows, not the columns.

To SUM the fields just use the operators.

Try this code:

`SELECT ( Biomass + Fossil + Brown + Coal ) AS result
FROM test
WHERE ID = '0';`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT [DateTime],
    SUM(Biomass + 
    [Fossil Brown coal/Lignite] + 
    [Fossil Coal-derived gas]) AS MySum
FROM test
WHERE Index = 0
GROUP BY [DateTime]
```

FYI - You may want to think about renaming some of your columns to something that does not over-utilize special characters like it does.

EDIT (for MySQL):

```
SELECT `DateTime`,
    SUM(Biomass + 
    `Fossil Brown coal/Lignite` + 
    `Fossil Coal-derived gas`) AS MySum
FROM test
WHERE Index = 0
GROUP BY `DateTime`
```

Comment: I am getting an error like this. Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[DateTime], SUM(Biomass + [Fossil Brown coal/Lignite] + [Fossil Coal-derived gas' at line 1

Comment: Since you are getting MySQL feedback, I am going to assume the correct RDBMS is MySQL and not SQL-Server. Try the update.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding i do that,

```
create table #temp([index] int identity(0,1),DateTime datetime,Biomass int,Fossil int,Brown int,[coal/Lignite] int
,[Fossil_Coal-derived] int,gas int)

select * from #temp

insert into #temp(DateTime,Biomass,Fossil,Brown,[coal/Lignite],[Fossil_Coal-derived],gas)
values('2/3/2018 23:30',4801,17356,589,1246,5200,192)

select SUM([Biomass]+[Fossil]+[Brown]+[coal/Lignite]+[Fossil_Coal-derived]+[gas]) total
From #temp
Where [index] = '0'
Group by DateTime
```